# knitr doesn't print plots in latex document

Tags: r, latex, knitr

Here is the minimal code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
ggplot
<<eval=TRUE>>=
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=hp)) + geom_point()
@

base
<<eval=TRUE>>=
with(mtcars, plot(hp ~ mpg))
@
\end{document}
```

and when I knit this using R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09),I only get the following:

```
ggplot
> require(ggplot2)
> ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=hp)) + geom_point()
base
> with(mtcars, plot(hp ~ mpg))
1
```

without any figures on my latex document. Why doesn't the code above print the plot in the pdf?

Comment: Why are you using `\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}` if you are using `knitr`? I can't knit with that line at all, but if I delete it I see plots just fine.

Comment: Also, how are you knitting? Have you tried `knit2pdf` or are you just clicking a button. If the latter, what is your RStudio preference for Weaving engine (see Options/Sweave, first preference)?

Comment: @BondedDust that was my initial thought too, but I don't think it's the case here because (a) knitr handles that well and makes it a non-issue and (b) there's a base plot in there as well which OP says is also missing.

Comment: Just calling knit on that text file, I get a warning about perhaps needing to instead use `Sweave2knitr` at my console, and a text Latex file and a new directory with two pdf-plots in my working directory.

Comment: And when I follow Gregor's lead I get a .tex file that when "typeset" in Texshop appears to deliver the desired result.

Comment: @Gregor Rstudio automatically adds `\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}` when I press `compile pdf` button. I tried using `knit2pdf`, but the problem still persists.

Comment: Okay, sounds like a duplicate [of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15043950/903061). Update RStudio, make sure your RStudio preference is set to knitr not Sweave, and if still necessary manually delete that line.

Comment: Actually after tinkering with Rstudio, I figured it out. `Weave Rnw files using`  was set to `knitr` by default, but after changing it to `Sweave` and back to `knitr`, everything works fine now. I guess it was indeed Rstudio bug.