# cannot get python code to be displayed in an Rnw file

Tags: python, r, markdown, knitr

in the following MWE of calling a python chunk:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

Syntax highlighting also works for other languages in the \LaTeX{} or HTML output, if Highlight has been installed (and is in PATH).

<<hi-python, engine='python'>>=
x = 'hello, python world!'
print x
print x.split(' ')
@

\end{document}
```

the document compiles but the python code does not get rendered

Looking at the following line:

> Syntax highlighting also works for other languages in the \LaTeX{} or
>   HTML output, if Highlight has been installed (and is in PATH).

I have installed highlight `sudo apt-get install highlight` (and also installed the r package `install.packages("highlight")` to cover both bases. I suspect highlight may not be in my PATH. How do I do this?

I have python installed:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

so what could be the problem?

Comment: If you remove `\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}` from your headers, it works, see: 
https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/098-highlight-python.Rnw

Comment: this is probably going to sound a but strange...but when I click on compile document within rstudio, that line gets automatically written into the document. I seem to have no control over this. I can set to FALSE, but the code still won't appear.

Comment: When I use Ubuntu this line is not included, but when I use MS, it is. But you are using Ubuntu, too, or?

Comment: I'm using Linux mint so really the behavior should be the same

Comment: look at this, even it goes for windows. Read the last answer, perhaps it is something in the global options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15040064/knitr-compile-problems-with-rstudio-windows

Comment: Pretty sure you were using Sweave instead of knitr: http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/rstudio/